# Audio player in background controlled by script in front - chrome extension

Tags: javascript, audio, google-chrome-extension

I am able to set an audio element in the background and control from the content script. However, I am creating two audio elements and since i want the content script audio element to be a normal player (with a play button and controls) the sound always overlaps. Both players, in the background and in the content script play at the same time. 
If I were to control the background audio element with a simple button in the content script it would work since there is no audio element in the front to be played and I would simply tell the background audio to play / stop playing. The audio element requires one... How can I do this?

```
//CONTENT SCRIPT

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   var audioEL = document.getElementById('stream');
   audioEL.addEventListener('play', streamOrder);
   audioEL.addEventListener('pause', streamOrder);
});


function streamOrder () {
   chrome.extension.sendMessage({ msg: "manageStream" });
}


// BACKGROUND SCRIPT
var STREAM_STATE = false

function manageStream () {
if(!STREAM_STATE) {
    if(document.getElementById('player') == undefined) document.write('<audio id="player" src="XXXXX">');
    document.getElementById('player').play();
    STREAM_STATE = true
}
  else {
    document.getElementById('player').pause();
    STREAM_STATE = false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made my own mp3 player. Since I create a button rather than an audio element I am able to control the stream.